# media module - simple picture upload

Tags: 7, media

Currently if using media module and users can upload pictures, they are presented with modal window where they can select a file for upload. On the same page there is a dropdown for selecting folder (taxonomy) and on second page there are fields for adding alt aln title text. Which is quite complicated for uploading one picture. 
Question:Is there any way of simplifying the process? Setting default upload directory for users and not to be asked to fill alt title fields?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the settings to skip field settings under

> admin/config/media/file-settings